# How to convert simple jQuery code to wordpress jQuery of the following code

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
    <b id="smsCount"></b> SMS (<b id="smsLength"></b>) Characters left
    <br /><textarea id="smsText" style="width:400px;height:200px">
    </textarea>


    //Plugin
    (function($){
      jQuery.fn.smsArea = function(options){

var
e = this,
cutStrLength = 0,

s = jQuery.extend({

    cut: true,
    maxSmsNum: 3,
    interval: 400,

    counters: {
        message: jQuery('#smsCount'),
        character: jQuery('#smsLength')
    },

    lengths: {
        ascii: [160, 306, 459],
        unicode: [70, 134, 201]
    }
    }, options);


e.keyup(function(){

    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){

        var
        smsType,
        smsLength = 0,
        smsCount = -1,
        charsLeft = 0,
        text = e.val(),
        isUnicode = false;

        for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
            switch(text[charPos]){
                case "\n": 
                case "[":
                case "]":
                case "\\":
                case "^":
                case "{":
                case "}":
                case "|":
                case "€":
                    smsLength += 2;
                break;

                default:
                    smsLength += 1;
            }

            //!isUnicode && text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€" && (isUnicode = true)
            if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
            isUnicode = true;
        }

        if(isUnicode)   smsType = s.lengths.unicode;
        else                smsType = s.lengths.ascii;

        for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

            cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
            if(smsLength <= smsType[sCount]){

                smsCount = sCount + 1;
                charsLeft = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
                break
            }
        }

        if(s.cut) e.val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
        smsCount == -1 && (smsCount = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft = 0);

        s.counters.message.html(smsCount);
        s.counters.character.html(charsLeft);

    }, s.interval)
}).keyup()
    }}(jQuery));


    //Start
    jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('#smsText').smsArea({maxSmsNum:3});
    });
```

I am working in Wordpress, M going to make some smscount system that counts  ASCII and Unicode character.I saw somewhere that Wordpress take jQuery instead of $. But it is not working. Dnt knw whr I make mistake?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `jQuery === $` if you define it in your script like `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});` or `(function($) {})(jQuery);`. Don't really understand your issue...

Comment: It works in normal script but not in Wordpress!!

Comment: Try to [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) it as a script that's dependant on `jQuery` instead of placing it inline ;)

Comment: I solved it by changing //Plugin
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
  jQuery.fn.smsArea = function(options){

Comment: @KirkBeard, Dnt U undrst& that? :p

Comment: @KrixnaaShrestha if anyone would have skipped vowels when talking to you, you'd have a major problem understanding what they are saying, most of the time. In a similar way, I could have given you a minimized and compressed version of `js` in my answer, which wouldn't have been as helpful. Also, remember not everyone around speaks native English. So make sure what you say is clear, understood and unqvcl. (For everyone else, that's *unequivocal*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change...

```
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('#smsText').smsArea({maxSmsNum:3});
});
```

... into...

```
(function($){
  $(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('#smsText').smsArea({maxSmsNum:e})
  })
})(jQuery);
```

If the element with `id="smsText"` exists in DOM and the script defining `smsArea()` function is ready/loaded at the time you are running the one above, you can remove the `document.ready` wrapper (remove lines `2` and `4` - without removing `3`!).

However, the key in the syntax above is not the `document.ready` wrapper,  but the one around it. the *"jQuery wrapper"*. You need to create a closure and pass `jQuery` as reference to it. This is the standard *"jQuery wrapper for WordPress"*, because at very rare times WP needs to have different versions of jQuery running on the same page (depending on what plugins/themes you load).

If you look at the function just above yours, it's wrapped in the same way.

A [more detailed explanation](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/) here.